# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>() is returning null from API response

Tags: c#, api

My problem is: I'm getting a null value as a response. I'm trying to get only one field, I need only "price" and when I'm trying to get it from the API

API Result: https://pastebin.com/M3G0mWyt

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await program.getBtcData(); 
    }

    private static async Task getBtcData()
    {
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync("The API link with my code goes here");

        Datum datum = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(response);

        Console.WriteLine(datum.price);
    }
}


public class Datum
{
    public float price { get; set; }
    public int price_btc { get; set; }
    public long market_cap { get; set; }
    public float percent_change_24h { get; set; }
   
}
```

This is a fragment of the JSON response for the API, the `timeSeries` array has many records within the array.

```json
{
    "config": {
        "data": "assets",
        "symbol": "'BTC'"
    },
    "usage": {
        "day": 3,
        "month": 3
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "price": 46546.77152174,
            "price_btc": 1,
            "market_cap": 874289452443,
            "percent_change_24h": 3.82,
            "percent_change_7d": 17.16,
            "percent_change_30d": 40.51,
            "volume_24h": 42197482726.49,
            "max_supply": "21000000",
            "timeSeries": [
                {
                    "asset_id": 1,
                    "time": 1628611200,
                    "open": 45201.72925621,
                    "close": 44842.06072819,
                    "high": 45246.68856158,
                    "low": 44695.7885183,
                    "volume": 2014656098.98,
                    "market_cap": 843108422454,
                    "url_shares": 2680,
                    "unique_url_shares": 1083,
                    "reddit_posts": null,
                    "reddit_posts_score": null,
                    "reddit_comments": null,
                    "reddit_comments_score": null,
                    "tweets": 16364,
                    "tweet_spam": 8162,
                    "tweet_followers": 101986337,
                    "tweet_quotes": 257,
                    "tweet_retweets": 6377,
                    "tweet_replies": 2697,
                    "tweet_favorites": 28077,
                    "tweet_sentiment1": 551,
                    "tweet_sentiment2": 1847,
                    "tweet_sentiment3": 1538,
                    "tweet_sentiment4": 11693,
                    "tweet_sentiment5": 735,
                    "tweet_sentiment_impact1": 1768663,
                    "tweet_sentiment_impact2": 11388640,
                    "tweet_sentiment_impact3": 6259652,
                    "tweet_sentiment_impact4": 75941973,
                    "tweet_sentiment_impact5": 6664817,
                    "social_score": 102026425,
                    "average_sentiment": 3.6,
                    "sentiment_absolute": 3,
                    "sentiment_relative": 84,
                    "search_average": null,
                    "news": 22,
                    "price_score": 3.8,
                    "social_impact_score": 4.3,
                    "correlation_rank": 3,
                    "galaxy_score": 73.5,
                    "volatility": 0.02172477,
                    "alt_rank": 149,
                    "alt_rank_30d": 27,
                    "market_cap_rank": 1,
                    "percent_change_24h_rank": 1960,
                    "volume_24h_rank": 2,
                    "social_volume_24h_rank": 1,
                    "social_score_24h_rank": 1,
                    "medium": null,
                    "youtube": null,
                    "social_contributors": 15891,
                    "social_volume": 17469,
                    "price_btc": 1,
                    "social_volume_global": 69887,
                    "social_dominance": 24.996065076480605,
                    "market_cap_global": 1954564708549,
                    "market_dominance": 43.135354832017505,
                    "percent_change_24h": -2.363770971407853
                }
            ],
            "social_dominance_calc_24h_previous": 0,
            "social_contributors_calc_24h_previous": 199497,
            "url_shares_calc_24h_previous": 50803,
            "tweet_spam_calc_24h_previous": 169920,
            "news_calc_24h_previous": 465,
            "average_sentiment_calc_24h_previous": 3.6,
            "social_score_calc_24h_previous": 1720730640,
            "social_volume_calc_24h_previous": 317814,
            "alt_rank_30d_calc_24h_previous": 35,
            "alt_rank_calc_24h_previous": 103,
            "social_dominance_calc_24h": 0,
            "social_dominance_calc_24h_percent": 0,
            "social_contributors_calc_24h": 140102,
            "social_contributors_calc_24h_percent": 70.22762247051334,
            "url_shares_calc_24h": 57014,
            "url_shares_calc_24h_percent": 112.22565596519891,
            "tweet_spam_calc_24h": 140547,
            "tweet_spam_calc_24h_percent": 82.71362994350282,
            "news_calc_24h": 433,
            "news_calc_24h_percent": 93.11827956989247,
            "average_sentiment_calc_24h": 3.5,
            "average_sentiment_calc_24h_percent": 97.22222222222221,
            "social_score_calc_24h": 1383209708,
            "social_score_calc_24h_percent": 80.38502226007901,
            "social_volume_calc_24h": 315465,
            "social_volume_calc_24h_percent": 99.26088844418433,
            "asset_id": 1,
            "time": 1628697600,
            "open": 46501.45088605,
            "high": 46532.57066649,
            "low": 46314.43464893,
            "volume": 502699651.09,
            "url_shares": 3518,
            "unique_url_shares": 955,
            "tweets": 20587,
            "tweet_spam": 7624,
            "tweet_followers": 102455405,
            "tweet_quotes": 164,
            "tweet_retweets": 2864,
            "tweet_replies": 1122,
            "tweet_favorites": 11256,
            "tweet_sentiment1": 664,
            "tweet_sentiment2": 1799,
            "tweet_sentiment3": 4400,
            "tweet_sentiment4": 13053,
            "tweet_sentiment5": 671,
            "tweet_sentiment_impact1": 4705176,
            "tweet_sentiment_impact2": 25628013,
            "tweet_sentiment_impact3": 8888460,
            "tweet_sentiment_impact4": 58528967,
            "tweet_sentiment_impact5": 4720195,
            "social_score": 102474329,
            "average_sentiment": 3.5,
            "sentiment_absolute": 3,
            "sentiment_relative": 85,
            "news": 18,
            "price_score": 3.2,
            "social_impact_score": 3,
            "correlation_rank": 5,
            "galaxy_score": 73.5,
            "volatility": 0.00851963,
            "alt_rank": 107,
            "alt_rank_30d": 47,
            "market_cap_rank": 1,
            "percent_change_24h_rank": 1132,
            "volume_24h_rank": 2,
            "social_volume_24h_rank": 1,
            "social_score_24h_rank": 1,
            "social_contributors": 5454,
            "social_volume": 21579,
            "social_volume_global": 86452,
            "social_dominance": 24.960671817887384,
            "market_cap_global": 2067216494026,
            "market_dominance": 42.27625383507646,
            "medium": 1,
            "youtube": 1,
            "reddit_posts": 11,
            "reddit_posts_score": 12,
            "reddit_comments": 8,
            "reddit_comments_score": 8,
            "tags": "",
            "close": 46546.77152174
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How can we possibly help here? We have no idea what the API is returning.

Comment: If this is a console app, you don't need to create an instance of `Program`; the host does that for you. `getBtcData()` returns nothing, and the program expects nothing. 0 is the normal exit code for console applications. I suggest using something like `Console.WriteLine("The price returned was: {0}", datum.price);` so that you know it's the `Console.WriteLine` code that's producing what you're seeing.

Comment: @DavidG I'm so sorry, I forgot to paste the link. https://pastebin.com/M3G0mWyt This is what the API is returning. I can't paste all classes in my code here, because the code is too long to post a question.

Comment: Please don't post things in comments, [edit] your question with the relevant details.

Comment: Sure, I added the link to the question.

Comment: Also posting external links is a bad thing since they might get removed which makes the question meaningless. Consider posting a [mre]

Comment: Okay, that's my first question. Sorry for that

Comment: The API aspect is not the issue here, the data response structure does not match the class you are deserializing.

Comment: Your `Datum` class is only a partial match to properties within an element inside the `Data` _array_ in the response.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand that my datum is only a partial match to properties but as I said I pasted only a part, I can't paste it all because It's too long for a question.

Comment: Your _program_ is returning `0` because it is completing correctly. There is no code in your program to return anything else, but that is not your actual problem, I've edited the question so you can focus on one issue at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your representation for `Datum` is only a small fragment of the entire JSON payload. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` tries to deserialize the entire payload into the requested structure of `T`. By default it is happy to omit the members that are missing from `T` but in your case it is only going to try and match the properties in the root of the JSON to your `Datum` and none of the property names match.

> `Datum` in this case represents part of one of the elements in a nested array. Many APIs have a route or query syntax that will allow you to restrict the data response to select the specific elements that you need. You should consult your API documentation as your expectation in this case is grossly different to what is actually returned from the API.

One way to make it match is to replicate the structure of the response in some C# classes to represent the DTOs in the response (*Data Transfer Objects*), but still note that in this solution there will be an array of `Datum`, you will need to verify if it is appropriate to use just the first one, or if you need to handle all the elements:

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await program.getBtcData(); 
    }

    private static async Task getBtcData()
    {
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync("The API link with my code goes here");

        var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseDTO>(response);
        var datum = dto.Data.FirstOrDefault();
        if (datum != null)
            Console.WriteLine(datum.price);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No data returned");
    }
}


public class ResponseDTO
{
    public ConfigDTO Config { get; set; }
    public UsageDTO Usage { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; } = new List<Datum>();
}
public class ConfigDTO
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
public class UsageDTO
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
}
public class Datum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public float price { get; set; }
    public int price_btc { get; set; }
    public long market_cap { get; set; }
    public float percent_change_24h { get; set; }
}
```